# Getting the partial sums of a List[Int] into a List[Long]

Tags: scala, list

I have a `List[Int]` that I read from the input.
I would like to get the partial sums of that list into a `List[Long]`.

```
val a: List[Int] = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt).toList
val sumList: List[Long] = a.scanLeft(0)(_.toLong + _.toLong).tail.toList
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
  Solution.scala:54: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Long
 required: Int
            val sumList: List[Long] = a.scanLeft(0)(_.toLong + _.toLong).tail.toList
                                                             ^
Solution.scala:54: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: List[Long]
            val sumList: List[Long] = a.scanLeft(0)(_.toLong + _.toLong).tail.toList
                                                                              ^
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0` should be `0L`. The "zero-value" of most functional operations seems to be the base for type inference.

Comment: In Scala, type inference flows from left-to-right through (but not within) argument lists. So, the types in the second argument list are inferred based on the first argument list, i.e. the `0L`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make the initial `List` a `List[Long]`, since you're casting the `Int`s to `Long`s anyway?

```
val a: List[Long] = readLine().split(" ").map(_.toLong).toList
val sumList: List[Long] = a.scanLeft(0L)(_ + _).tail.toList
```